# Returning a char** gives me error "Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or free'd

Tags: c

I need to return a list of strings. Those strings are read from the file (each string in each line of the file). The code below is not working:

```
void getStrings(char **container, FILE* file, int *numberOfLetters) {
  char* line = NULL;
  size_t l = 0;
  ssize_t r;
  container =  (char**) malloc (sizeof(char*));
  size_t lettersNumber= 1;
  size_t numberOfStrings = 0;
  size_t sizeOfContainer = 1;
  while ((r = getline(&line, &l, file)) != -1) {
    line[strlen(line) - 1] = '\0';
    lettersNumber = lettersNumber + strlen(line);
    if (numberOfStirngs == sizeOfContainer) {
      sizeOfContainer= sizeOfContainer * 2;
      char** temp = calloc(sizeOfContainer, sizeof(char**));
      for (int k = 0; k < l; k++) {
        temp[k] = container[k];
      }
      free(container);
      container = temp;
    }
    container[numberOfStrings] = line;
    numberOfStrings++;
  } 
  if (line) {
    free(line);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you `calloc` the whole array of pointers in each step, you loose all the strings from previous iterations and always only keep the last line. Since you use `calloc`, all these pointers are null, thus your error message.

The tool that is foreseen for such things is `realloc` and not `malloc` or `calloc` to keep the values that you already have stored.

There seem to be other things wrong, too. E.g you have only one `line`, all your lines are copied into that one, so previous lines are always overwritten. As BLUEPIXY correctly notes, you only change the value of your function parameter to the new values, you never return the new value to the caller.

Then, re-allocating memory in each iteration is a real waste. You should think of a strategy to do that more efficiently.

Comment: The essence of this problem is call by value.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, I am overwriting line in each iteration, but also in each iteration I copy the line to the `container`. What is more, I do not realloc memory in each iteration -> only when `NumberOfStrings == sizeOfContainer`. So where specificly do I loose all of the previous Strings?

Comment: Call by value? Could you please be more specific?

Comment: @michalwojciech, no you don't copy the line to the container, you copy the address of the line to the container.

Comment: Will `strcpy(container[numberOfStrings], line)` do the copying part?

Comment: See my edit for the call by value. Before continuing to program with pointers, you should really take a break and read up about the C function model (call by value) and about the C memory model and pointers. In this state of knowledge that you are, your code makes not much sense and is unrecoverable.

Comment: No, `strcpy` alone will not be sufficient, you also have to allocate space for the new line that you want to store. In C, all allocations are explicit.